# Drupal submitting a query that change a tableselect

Tags: php, forms, drupal

I'm new on drupal, i've create a module that shows a form with select, button submit and i've got a tableselect that lists some records (from database). the tableselect works and it's listing all records, but i want to "filter" records on this tableselect by selecting what i want to see with select list (and submitting). when i choose something in the select list and i submit, the tableselect dont change but if i execute a dsm($form['tableselect']) it said that tableselect contains what the db_query returns.

here is my form :

```
 function myBook_form ($form, &$form_state){

  $form = array();
  $form['options_state'] = array(
  '#type' => 'value',
  '#value' => array (
    'all'=>t('All'),
    'Valid'=>t('Valid'),
    'published'=>t('published'),
    'not published'=>t('not published')

    )

  );


 $form['state_book'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => t('state :'),                     
'#options' => $form['options_state']['#value'],        
 );


  // filter submit button

 $form['filter'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('filter')                
);
}


$header  = array(
'book_title' => t('title'),
'book_state' => t('state'),   
  );

$sql = db_select('field_data_field_title','ta');
$sql->join('field_data_field_state','st','st.entity_id = ta.entity_id');


$sql
    ->fields('ta',   array('field_title_value','entity_id'))       
    ->fields('st',array('field_state_value'));
    $result = $sql->execute();


$rows = array();



foreach ($result as $res){ 

  $rows [] = array(
    'book_title' => l($res->field_title_value,  'node/'.$res->entity_id),
    'book_state' => $res->field_state_value           
  );  

 }

 $form['table1'] = array(
'#type' => 'tableselect',
'#header' => $header,
'#options' => $rows,
'#empty' => t('empty !'),

  );


 return $form;
```

here is my submit function :

```
function book_form_submit($form, &$form_state){



 $cond = $form_state['values']['state_book'];


$header  = array(
'book_title' => t('title'),
'book_state' => t('state'),
 );

   $sql = db_select('field_data_field_title','ta');
   $sql->join('field_data_field_state','st','st.entity_id = ta.entity_id');

  $sql
    ->fields('ta', array('field_title_value'))        
    ->fields('st',array('field_state_value'));


  $sql->condition('st.field_state_value', $cond, '=');       



 $quer = $sql->execute();


$rows = array();

 foreach ($quer as $q){ 

    array_push($rows, array(
    'book_title' => $q->field_title_value,
    'book_state' => $q->field_state_value,

      ));

      }    
    $form['table2'] = array(
   '#type' => 'tableselect',
   '#header' => $header,
   '#options' => $rows,
   '#empty' => t('empty!')
  );   
   }
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you expecting this to work with ajax? Show us your function that builds the form. You should not be altering the form in the submit function.

Comment: I think it will work with ajax, the problem is : where i'm supposed to put the '#ajax' callback ? on the submit button or on the select list ?

Comment: i want to "filter" the table select by selecting on a select list and submitting, the table select have to change after that and will contains only what i select

Comment: If you want the ajax to fire when the select button is pressed, the you would put the '#ajax' callback on the submit button. But, like I said in the first comment, you should not be altering the form in the submit handler, it should all be done in the form build function. Without seeing the form build function, I can not help you any more.

Comment: It is unclear where is piece of code is located as you have not included the function names. Why do you have 2 submit functions? What is your form actually doing other than just filtering the table?

Comment: I just re edit it sorry

Comment: i've just one submit function, i've just past it 2 times on the post

Comment: As your just filtering a list, why do you not just use the views module with an exposed filter? It would be much easier. Why exactly do you need the table select? If you need the table select to do something to the selected books, maybe the views bulk operations would help

Comment: I'm developing a back office for my web site, so i want to show books not on front but just for the admin

Comment: i mean i dont want to display my form on a drupal page

Comment: i tried ajax on button (with callback and wrapper) and i've put preffix and suffix on tableselect (just after '#empty') now the submitting make a refresh on tableselect but it shows : empty rows (it seems like #options dont work)

Comment: Try creating a view with VBO as 2pha advised, specify the path starting with `admin/YourView` & set the permission for admin only

Comment: read this page (specifically the part "Your form builder function builds it a different way based on that input ($form_state)"):https://www.drupal.org/node/752056